# How to integrate PHPUnit to a custom framework

Tags: php, frameworks, phpunit

I'd like to integrate PHPUnit to my framework.
By this, I mean that I have to do some initializing in the beginning, like setting up autoloads, before I'd run the tests.

I'd like to use the cli test runner, and if I understand correctly, I have to make a class, that has a static function suite(), which returns an instance of PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite, and add tests to this suite, as noted on http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html.

So far I have come up with:

```
class MyTestFW {
    public static function suite() {
        // Do framework initialization here

        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite();
        $suite->addTest(new SimpleTest());

        // Add more tests

        return $suite;
    }
}
```

SimpleTest is a very basic test class, that extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.
When I run "phpunit MyTestFW", I always get:

```
PHPUnit 3.3.16 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 0 seconds

There was 1 error:

1) (SimpleTest)
RuntimeException: PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::$name must not be NULL.
```

Could someone help me out a little please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::$name` gets set in the TestCase constructor, so you could try this:

```
$suite->addTest(new SimpleTest('simpletest'));
```

**edit1:**

I don't know your code, so i don't know if this helps.
What I usually see is this (as a replacement of the above, not addition):

```
$suite->addTestSuite('SimpleTest');
```

**edit2:**

[phpunit documentation: Chapter 7 - Organizing Tests](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.filesystem)

Comment: Nope, it looks it's trying to call it as a method:

There was 1 failure:

1) SimpleTest(SimpleTest)
Method SimpleTest does not exist

Comment: Adding it to addTestSuite() didn't help either :(

Comment: can you provide more code? the SimpleTest class itself would be nice to see

Comment: Sure:
class SimpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testSimple() {
        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}

Comment: so, if you replace $suite->addTest(new SimpleTest()); with $suite->addTestSuite('SimpleTest');, it still does not work?

Comment: My mistake, it works. I put the 'SimpleTest' string in the testcase's constructor. Now I just need some best practices, thank you!